# android camera intent - retrieving image URI on any device

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to create a feature in my app where the user can:

- press a button to open the camera `(Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`
- take a picture and save it
- optionally crop the picture (requires the uri of image)
- display the picture

Ideally, I would like to create the image in a temporary directory only. The problem I'm having is that it seems as though any use of the camera is very device dependent. For example, on my phone, if I pass the argument `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT = xyz` to the camera intent I will get two copies of the image. One in the default location and one in `xyz`. I've heard on some devices it will only store to one or the other and one might be a thumbnail image only.

If I do not specific an output location, is there a surefire way to get the Uri of the (full)image created by camera? I've seen solutions on this site, but again, many people are suggesting it doesn't work on various devices. At least If I can find the image once, I can copy it and delete the original.

Would it be possible just to let the camera save to default location, then perhaps either specific the file name beforehand and search for that filename? Or search for the most recent photograph? I'd like to think these would work but perhaps someone will tell me this won't work on some devices.